# Remove class when scrolled to the href atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I remove class from the element in 2000

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
}, 2000);
```

How can I amend my code to remove class when the 'autoscroll' is finished?

```
  $('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .button, .footer2 a').click(function() {
event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered, eg will not change links name
var windowSize = $(window).width();
if (windowSize >= 769) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 51
  }, 1500);
}
else if (windowSize <= 768) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 102
  }, 1500);
}
return false; });
```

I guess I should somehow use `attribute href`, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by defining a complete callback into animate method.

```
$('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .button, .footer2 a').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered, eg will not change links name
  var windowSize = $(window).width();
  var scrollY;

  if (windowSize >= 769) {
    scrollY = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 51;
  } else {
    scrollY = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 102;
  }

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollY
  }, 1500, function() {
    $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Works as requested, thanks
PS. Will give it correct answer in 5 minutes, as cant do it now

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) takes a final argument *complete* function, so you should be able to write something like:

```
$('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .button, .footer2 a').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var windowSize = $(window).width();
  if (windowSize >= 769) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 51
    }, 1500, function() {
      $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
    });
  } else if (windowSize <= 768) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 102
    }, 1500, function() {
      $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```